# Trying to understand why is next.js Image component resizing when overlaping a div element on top

Tags: css, reactjs, position, css-position

I am trying to make an image uploader in React that uses an image component the user can interact with. If the user hovers over the image, a delete button appears.  I use position: relative to set the position of the div on top of the image. I want all of the images to be the same width and height so they can be displayed nicely in a grid. The code works as intended with most images but for some images, the image width gets resized when the user is hovering on top of it. I tried setting the width of the picture to a constant value in different ways, but it did not prevent the width from shrinking.

I tried using relative position for the div named button_container in order to get the buttons to overlap with the images. I expected the height of the image to stay unchanged but that is not what happened. I noticed that using absolute position solves the issue.
I also noticed that if I increase the width of the div around the image by say 100px I can use absolute position and get the error to disappear.

I am not sure what is causing the error in the first place and why adding width to the div is helping or why using relative positioning gives a different behavior from absolute positioning.

Image js:

filename: ImageErrorReproduce.js

```
import styles from "./ImageErrorReproduce.module.css";
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react';
import carImg from 'public/images/uploads/toyota 2.jpg'

export default function PreviewImage(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.preview_image}>
                <Image src={carImg} height={150} width={200} alt="" />
                <div>
                    <div className={styles.button_container}>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className={styles.remove_button}
                            onClick={() => (console.log("Delete button clicked"))}
                        >
                            <Icon icon="heroicons-outline:trash"
                                color="red"
                                width={30}
                            />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Image css

filename: ImageErrorReproduce.module.css

```
.remove_button {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

.preview_image { 
    display: flex;
    width: 202px;
    flex-direction: row;
} 

.button_container {
    display: none;
}

.preview_image:hover .button_container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative; 
    right: 70px;
    width: 70px; 
}
```

Screenshots of the issue:
[before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FjM.png)

[on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCrzY.png)